# How to solve if same month have different rates in data stage or sql?

Tags: sql

Input:

```
SDO Startmonth  endmonth rate
101    jan          mar    10
101    feb          mar    20
101    may          jul     30
```

Output:

```
SDO  Startmonth Endmonth rate
101    may        jul     30
```

I need to reject the entire column which is having different rates in same period and i need to get column which is having unique rate.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: It would be a **lot** easier if you stored the months as numbers and not as strings

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question, you have 3 differents periods in your data sample

Comment: @Cid: I think bhargav wants to show all valid periods. Periods are only valid when there doesn't exist an overlapping period with another rate.

Comment: @bhargav: "Input" is what is in your table and "Output" is a desired query result? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Are you looking for an algorithm? Or do you have an algorithm and don't know how to translate it into SQL? Or do you have a query, but it's not working as expected?

Comment: for eg:may and july are not repeated in any of the above rows that means rates dont differ for the months.Just want the months that are not overlapped

Comment: "I need to reject the entire column" ...you mean _row_, not column, right? Also please answer Thorsten's queries.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a standard logic written in MSSQL Server. You can use the same logic as per your DBMS-

```
WITH your_table(SDO,Startmonth,endmonth,rate)
AS
(
SELECT 101,'jan','mar',10 UNION ALL
SELECT 101,'Feb','mar',20 UNION ALL
SELECT 101,'may','jul',30
)
,st_month 
AS(
    SELECT SDO, Startmonth
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY SDO,Startmonth
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Startmonth) <> COUNT(Startmonth)
)
,end_month AS (
    SELECT SDO, endmonth
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY SDO,endmonth
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT endmonth) <> COUNT(endmonth)
)

SELECT A.* 
FROM your_table A
LEFT JOIN st_month B ON A.SDO = B.SDO
    AND A.Startmonth = B.Startmonth
LEFT JOIN end_month C ON A.SDO = C.SDO
    AND A.endmonth = C.endmonth
WHERE B.SDO IS NULL AND C.SDO IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following if you are using Sqlserver:

```
Select *
from
(
    select 
    case when tab2.SDO is null then tab1.SDO else tab2.SDO end as SDO,
    case when tab2.Startmonth is null then tab1.Startmonth else tab2.Startmonth end as Startmonth,
    case when tab2.endmonth is null then tab1.endmonth else tab2.endmonth end as endmonth,
    case when tab2.rate is null then tab1.rate else tab2.rate end as rate
    from your_table tab1
    left join your_table tab2
    on (tab2.Startmonth > tab1.Startmonth
        and tab2.Startmonth < tab1.endmonth ) or
        tab2.Startmonth is null
) as tab
group by SDO,Startmonth,endmonth,rate
having count(*) = 1
```

Example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b7db8165867b33a557ad973130580c64)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your "month" columns are really dates, you can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.startmonth <= t.endmonth and
                        t2.endmonth >= t.startmonth and
                        t2.rate <> t.rate
                 );
```

This uses basic overlap logic that says that two intervals overlaps if each starts on or before the other ends.

The `<=` and `>=` imply that the start and end months are both included in the period.  The code can be adjusted if one or both end months are not included.